# Debian 9: can't use sudo

Tags: debian, sudo, root

I've recently installed Debian 9 and encountered the following error.

During installation I've set up **'root'** password and  I've set up **'user'** with his own password. Later when I log into **'user'** account and want to install some package I have this problem. If I run:

```
sudo apt-get install 'package'
```

then I get this message:

```
'user' is not in sudoers list
```

And if I try to log into **'root'** terminal with:

```
su
```

and enter password, I get:

```
su: Authentification error
```

P.S. I understand that question may be really silly, but I've not found any information about it in internet, so I need to ask it here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems you have been bitten by a bug in the Debian 9 installer, as described in this forum topic: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=133604

There's a workaround given in the (currently) last post in that thread.

As I recall, the sudo command is not configured in Debian unless there is no root password given on install. Formerly, the sudo command was not even installed by default in Debian.

Comment: I think [this post](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=133596&p=647964#p647964) (linked from the thread you linked) is more relevant. You should [edit] in the salient points to your answer, because links can break.

Comment: Also, [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=866206)

Comment: It's a known bug in the installer.

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugrepo ... bug=866206

edit: IMO the easiest way to fix this is - 

1. When grub starts, hit 'e' to edit the startup environment.

2. In the editor, find the line that starts with 'linux' and add 

CODE: SELECT ALL
init=/bin/bash


to the end of that line and hit esc or F10 to boot the machine.

3. Next, remount your root filesystem read-write like this -

CODE: SELECT ALL
mount -no remount,rw /


4. Change root's password like this - 

CODE: SELECT ALL
passwd root


5. Reboot. Done  :)

Comment: You have to use the root user password when you execute `su` *not* your user's password.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may not have added your non-root user to the list of `sudoers`.  See `man sudoers` for details on this.

As for the second question, are you certain that you are using `root`'s password?  Unlike `sudo`, which asks for *your* password, `su` will ask for the password of the user to which you are switching.

Comment: It is a bug in the Debian 9 installer that is hitting people at the moment, as mentioned, but not explained properly, in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

> su: Authentification error

You are getting `su: Authentication failure` because you are trying to become root (which maybe disabled). Note `su root` will want the 'root' password and not the 'user' password.

Instead of `su` using `sudo -i` or better yet, append to any command `sudo` in the way of:

```
    sudo apt-get install something
    [sudo] password for user:
```

> 'user' is not in sudoers list

You can add the user to the `sudo` group:

```
sudo adduser <username> sudo
```

The change will take effect after next login.

This works because `/etc/sudoers` is pre-configured to grant permissions to all members of this group . Though you should not make any changes to this:

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

As long as you have access to a user that is in the same groups as your "original" user, you can delete the old one.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is to edit /etc/group while booted a different way.  Add your normal username to the sudo line (& group) at the end.  Reboot.  Then in a terminal as that user type sudo passwd root and enter a new password.

Booting from a live CD or in rescue mode from an install disk would probably work.  I happen to have OpenBSD installed on the same drive so I used that.

The clue is in the /etc/sudoers file:

## Allow members of group sudo to execute any command

%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

Just get yourself into the sudo group, you don't need to mess with the sudoers file at all.  I just tried a cold boot and logged in as root to test it.

Answer (score -1):

There should be a file called `sudoers`; locate that (in `/etc` probably (I can't tell you directly as I'm not on a Linux systems and mine is somewhere else, probably). `man sudoers` should tell you where it is.

You will need to enable your user to use `sudo` in there.

As noted in the `sudoers` file itself, and elsewhere, there are dire warnings about editing this file directly. Use the `visudo` command instead, as that will help to stop you shooting yourself in the foot. Despite its name, `visudo` will not necessarily use `vi` to edit the file; it will use your favourite editor, as set by the `EDITOR` environment variable.

Comment: I rather assumed he would read the manual page, and/or the actual file - which on my system at least have dire warnings that you *must* use `visudo`! I have no idea why my correct answer was downvoted.

Comment: I would reiterate, if you _are_ going to edit `/etc/sudoers` then `visudo` is designed to stop you shooting yourself in the foot - if ___it___ thinks there is an error in the file after your edit it but before it is finally saved then so will ___`sudo`___ and that will lock you out of using _sudo_ to, er, do the things that it is essential to use it for...

Comment: I don't disagree. And that is obvious to anyone looking at the `sudoers` file.

Comment: "I have no idea why my correct answer was downvoted." Probably because you're telling somebody without root access to run a command only root can run. They can't `sudo` and they can't `su`; any solution that starts by assuming they have root isn't going to help them