# Debian Stretch: Can't invoke root from standard user account (possible wrong mount options)

Tags: debian, mount, root, debian-installer

I've installed Stretch(4.9.0-3) in a standard PC 2 weeks ago and all works perfectly fine.
But I recently downloaded a new DVD(3) same version to install this time in a usb-stick (3.0) without /swap.

**Note:** I have to say that it's much better install 1dvd then use internet because the installer looks bugged when ask to change to dvd#1, dvd#2 then dvd#1 again and never ask for dvd#3


So, I have a problem every time that I need to invoke the root from the standard user account: e.g. can't unlock account settings neither invoke root from the terminal and when open Software & updates nothing happens although I can check update from Settings->Details->CheckForUpdates.. there is nothing to update so I'm not sure I the standard user can update, probably not, but will ask for admin or what? 
[image: capture]

Although another StackExchange-user has a similar [issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378560/debian-9-cant-use-sudo): he did mention to sudo and lot of answers are related to that.

NOTE: I can access through tty and edit, update, upgrade without problems.
I think my problem could be given for the mount options that I chosen.
[image: picture]

You will not see something like *default* at options because I explicitly change that. And I think that *that-was-my-mistake*:
At the /root installation stage there was a problem with the installation options. I'm not sure if it was -noexec- and I unchecked it, or if it was -nodiratime- and I unchecked that but it was marked anyway in some other configuration. What I'm plenty sure is that I uncheck one of them and the installation process continue as normal.

Well.. that's my problem. Beyond that my Cross-Hardware environment works perfectly well. I hope a long time but the truth is that I don't know enough about SSD configuration. OH!! by the way **I'M NOT USING SWAP**

***What I will do:*** If you think there is no configuration problem with that mount options I will try from the tty in a to try to fix this without re install .

Please note that it makes no sense to reinstall if I'm doing wrong the mount options (that's would be my question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the permissions on the file. Google is your friend, most of the problems you face, other people have also faced and solved. One google search and you might just find your solution.

```
chmod 4755 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1
```

- The nosuid mount option specifies that the filesystem cannot contain set userid files. Preventing setuid binaries on a world-writable filesystem makes sense because there's a risk of root escalation or other awfulness there. In simple words, remove nosuid in /etc/fstab from all the partition's. Reboot, and then try Login.

Should be something like this:

```
UUID=a34cdfff-2388.. / ext4 noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

Comment: doesn't work :\

Comment: -rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 14856 Jul 15 20:26 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1

Comment: I think you're right but I think I'm doing wrong. I would try to change access to allow users.

Comment: -rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 14856 May 24 15:51 polkit-agent-helper-1
This is my polkit file. This is how it should be. I have edited the answer, now it should work.

Comment: I don't understand. chmod g+x doesn't change the group permissions but the time when modified was changed. Give me a minute

Comment: Don't try and mess up the permissions. Run the above answer I gave and it will work.

Comment: Ok g-s do it for me: -rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 14856 Jul 15 20:26 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1 But I still unavailable to invoke the root

Comment: sorry this is the good one: -rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 14856 Jul 15 20:53 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1

Comment: ok I will try your edited answer

Comment: 4755 does not work. I will try to reboot the computer because this makes not sense

Comment: Also check your /bin/su it should also have permission 4755. Change it just in case. chmod 4755 /bin/su

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work. I'm having problems to unmount /var I will investigate if it is related to this. Anyway you deserve a thumb up for be there helping unconditional.. And I'm sure the answer is around your answer

Comment: -rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 40536 Jul 15 01:29 /bin/su

Comment: The nosuid mount option specifies that the filesystem cannot contain set userid files. Preventing setuid binaries on a world-writable filesystem makes sense because there's a risk of root escalation or other awfulness there. In simple words, remove nosuid in /etc/fstab from the root partition. Reboot, and then try Login.

Comment: Just at /root or all of it?

Comment: SOrry @FedericoGallo. Yes remove nosuid on all of the partitions, and then restart.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62299/discussion-between-hunter-s-thompson-and-federico-gallo).

Comment: wahooooooooo! WONDERFUL! Could you edit the answer for clearance to other users? oh you just do it. Thank you thank you thank you :)