# Debian not logged in with proper password after upgrade

Tags: debian, ubuntu, security, login, pam

Just after upgrade my system start to fail when I try to login as normal user both via gdm and tty. However it's not possible to login as root too. When try to login via tty it outputs 'Login Incorrect'. Via the gdm the same but another words used. I've changed passwords with live cd but it's not helped. I tried to check logs, but last log changed before upgrade.

It's Debian system.

How to reslolve this? Thanks!

PS. chrooting from live cd to purpose system successfully done however.

Comment: Upgrade from Jessie to Stretch or what upgrade? And why are you giving the /ubuntu tag? Ubuntu doesn't have a root user. And what do you mean by *my system starts to fail*? You can't log in at all?

Comment: Boot in single-user mode, after that - change the password to root/user, reboot and try to log in again.

Comment: Sounds like a PAM issue to me. Check system logs (not lastlog) from your live system. Another idea: spawn a shell (with no getty or login) on a normally unused tty during boot (you'd have to set this up from the live system as well). With that shell, you'd be able to investigate what goes wrong during login (with strace, if need be).

Comment: Welcome to U&L , Debian or Ubuntu? Please [edit here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/386332/edit).

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378560/ is probably a related question, although this question does not properly identify the operating system or version.

Comment: Thanks for advance, I found the reason! So funny. I forgot about my second installation of the same debian system on `/dev/sdb1` and looks for reasons at `/dev/sda1`'s system. So however, there was just a half system at `sda` - `linux-generic` packet was removed and grub found the only system at `sdb`. Sorry for mislead from truth :)

Comment: So the problem is solved and it's not good to leave the question as unanswered. Either give yourself the answer and mark it as solution or delete the question (as it is irrelevant to future readers). Thank you.